# Robolectric asm NoSuchMethodError, classpath issue?

Tags: android, debugging, junit, intellij-idea, robolectric

After pulling the new changes (2.3-SNAPSHOT), all my app tests fail with the same result. The code fails when instanciating TestClass and precisely when the getConstructors() method is (reflectively) called. The exception raised is:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
at org.objectweb.asm.commons.GeneratorAdapter.invokeInsn(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.commons.GeneratorAdapter.invokeVirtual(Unknown Source)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader$ClassInstrumentor.instrumentConstructor(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:541)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader$ClassInstrumentor.instrument(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:422)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.getInstrumentedBytes(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:245)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.findClass(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:159)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:98)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:1517)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:39)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:75)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner.<init>(RobolectricTestRunner.java:649)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getHelperTestRunner(RobolectricTestRunner.java:289)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:206)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
[CUT]`

I am running inside Intellij IDEA and my .iml correctly shows:

`<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="asm-5.0.1" level="project" />`

Moreover, if I debug to the asm library, I do see:

`public void visitMethodInsn(int i, java.lang.String s, java.lang.String s1, java.lang.String s2, boolean b) { /* compiled code */ }`

I don't really know if it's related with Robolectric because all the standard tests pass when I do `mvn clean install`...what can be the problem?

Comment: Related to this, how can I see the classpath of my Debug Configuration in Intellij? And is there a way to regenerate the .iml file?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. It looks like there is a conflicting version of asm somewhere in your classpath, probably asm 4.x where it should be asm 5. Also, take care that asm comes in 2 forms : asm-all which contains all the classes of asm and asm, asm-utils, asm-tree, etc, that are split packages. This can also create conflicts.